# Kafka Streams measure througput: How much time passes to receive x messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a problem that really grinds my gears. I want to measure how fast my kafka producer produces messages to kafka. To do this I want to use KafkaStreams to tell me every 1k, 2k, 3k, etc. received messages how much time passed. Idealy the time starts on the first received message.
I probably need sliding windows, but can't find a good entrypoint. Does anybody have a tipp for me?
Thanks in advance!
Best regards,
Zuendelmeister

Comment: just suggestion: maybe take a look at kafka with zipkin sleuth integration (for tracing and monitoring performance). also kafka streams provide some jmx metrics, maybe there something that you will find useful for your use case.  also check micrometer integration

Comment: Why do you need KafkaStreams for this? The Producer exposes JMX metrics so you can get the information directly from the Producer itself: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producer_monitoring -- there is no need to measure it manually.